# node.js getting error when pressing new user

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEpZO.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uqaZ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLmOW.png)

add_user.ejs

```
<!--include header-->
<%- include('include/_header')%>
<!--/include header-->


<!-- Main Site -->
<main id="site-main">
    <div class="container">
       <div class="box-nav d-flex justify-between">
        <div class="filter">
            <a href="/"><i class="fas fa-backward"></i>Visi Naudotjai</a>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="form-title text-center">
           <h2 class="text-dark">Naujas naudotojas</h2>
           <span class="text-light">Naudokitės apačioja pateikta forma susikuriant nauja naudotojas</span>
       </div>
       
       <!-- add user form -->
       <%- include('include/_form')%>
    </div>
</main>
 <!-- /Main Site -->



<!--include footer-->
<%- include('include/_footer')%>
<!--/include footer-->
```

Cannot understand there is the problem when i try to presss on main site add new user its need to open a new tab with a new just form but i get just this error someone know there is mistake was made ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is because you're calling add_user.ejs, which is in the include page. So, you probably put the page in the wrong folder. If I'm wrong, you need to rename add_user.html to add_user.ejs, or use html as the View Engine

Comment: yes u are right :D it was in wrong folder :D thanks